# How to have only one mongodb instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im writting a node app to log some informations in a mongo database.

Below is the snippet code that called each time i need to store log in the mongo database.

```
const mongo = {}
const mongo_cli = require('mongodb').MongoClient

module.exports = {
    log (l) {
        mongo_cli.connect(the_mongo_url, (error, client) => {
            if (error) throw error;

            mongo.cli = client;
            mongo.db = client.db(the_database);

           //insert and update operations
        });
    }
}
```

The code above work for now. I mean, I can insert and update logs already inserted at the price of one (or more) connection (s) that I never close due to my lack of control of callback functions.

So, how can i structure it better so that i can just have only one mongo_cli call to not consume too many ressources ?

Comment: will singleton pattern help? ... singleton pattern is basically having only one object or instance.

Comment: @rakeshshrestha singleton pattern doesn't work.